# Multiprocessing, pooling and randomness

Tags: python, random, python-multiprocessing

I am experiencing a strange thing: I wrote a program to simulate economies. Instead of running this simulation one by one on one CPU core, I want to use multiprocessing to make things faster. So I run my code (fine), and I want to get some stats from the simulations I am doing. Then arises one surprise: all the simulations done at the same time yield the very same result! Is there some strange relationship between Pool() and random.seed()?

To be much clearer, here is what the code can be summarized as:

```
class Economy(object):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.run_number = i
        self.Statistics = Statistics()
        self.process()

def run_and_return(i):
    eco = Economy(i)
    return eco

collection = []
def get_result(x):
    collection.append(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    for i in range(NRUN):
        pool.apply_async(run_and_return, (i,), callback=get_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The process(i) is the function that goes through every step of the simulation, during i steps. Basically I simulate NRUN Economies, from which I get the Statistics that I put in the list collection.

Now the strange thing is that the output of this is exactly the same for the first 4 runs: during the same "wave" of simulations, I get the very same output. Once I get to the second wave, then I get a different output for the next 4 simulations!

All these simulations run well if I use the same program with processes=1: I get different results when I only work on one core, taking simulations one by one... I have tried a few things, but can't get my head around this, hence my post...

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this long post, do not hesitate to ask for more precisions!

All the best,

Comment: Wherea re you using `random` and how?

Comment: Yes Reut, I am using random A LOT in the process() function, that's why I didn't go into the details...
Thanks Oleh, I'll have a look at the documentation! It's still the strangest thing, since the target function have different input... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Linux then each pool process is made by forking the parent process. This means the process is literally duplicated - this includes the seed any random object may be using.

The random module selects the seed for its default functions on import. Meaning the seed has already been selected before you create the Pool.

To get around this you must use an initialiser for each pool process that sets the random seed to something unique.

A decent way to seed `random` would be to use the process id and the current time. The process id is bound to be unique on a single run of your program. Whilst using the time will ensure uniqueness over multiple runs in case the same process id is produced. Passing process id and time through as a string will mean that the digest of the string is also used to seed the random number generator -- meaning two similar strings will produce substantially different seeds. Alternatively, you could use the `uuid` module to generate seeds.

```
def proc_init():
    random.seed(str(os.getpid()) + str(time.time()))

pool = Pool(num_procs, initializer=proc_init)
```

Comment: That's probably it, I'm on Linux! So now I just have to check how to set a specific random seed for each process... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your precisions... but it's still the strangest thing: I do get different seeds for each worker in the pool, but the output of the Economy for the same "wave" of num_procs is still the same across the runs... when the seeds are not!
I am pretty sure that it's not coming from my code, because if I run it with num_procs = 1, I do get different results... Very strange!

Comment: I would have to disagree. To me it seems that there is some sort of starting state that is mutated by each run of Economy. There is an assumption that Economy will be run sequentially so that all runs with start with a different state. Instead, the starting state is being copied across to all the worker processes. They all start in the same state, so they all produce the same output. Without knowing the innards of `Statisitics` and `Economy` I can't say where this duplicated state is coming from (if not from `random`).

Comment: You were right Sir! I was not only using random, but also numpy.random, which behaves the same way... So each Pool of workers had the same seed for numpy, which explains the why! Thank you very much!

Best,

Max

Comment: Using `random.seed()` without arguments should take `os.urandom` as source for the seed. This should be better than time and PID.